# How to detect an CTS approved Android build?

Tags: android, android-pay, cts

In the documentation of Android N preview is mentioned:

> This early build is not Compatibility Test Suite (CTS) approved. Apps that depend on CTS approved builds won’t work (Android Pay for example).

In my Android app I want to check whether the device/build is CTS approved on the first launch. Is this possible? How does Android Pay do it?

Comment: Link to the documentation: http://developer.android.com/preview/support.html#general (might be outdated soon)

Answer (score 3):

The [SafetyNet API](http://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html) allows you to run a compatibility check which:

> allows your app to check if the device where it is running matches the profile of a device that has passed Android compatibility testing. The compatibility check creates a device profile by gathering information about the device hardware and software characteristics, including the platform build.

Once you have a connected `GoogleApiClient` using the `SafetyNet.API`, you can call

```
byte[] nonce = getRequestNonce(); // Should be at least 16 bytes in length.
SafetyNet.SafetyNetApi.attest(mGoogleApiClient, nonce)
.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onResult(SafetyNetApi.AttestationResult result) {
    Status status = result.getStatus();
    if (status.isSuccess()) {
      // Indicates communication with the service was successful.
      // result.getJwsResult() contains the result data
    } else {
      // An error occurred while communicating with the service
    }
  }
});
```

And parse the response as per [the instructions](http://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html#compat-check-response), looking for `"ctsProfileMatch": true` in the resulting JSON.

Comment: Nice, any ideas what to do if Google Play Services are not available?

Comment: Only Google has a list of devices that passed CTS, so without Google Play service's connection to Google's server, there's no way to check.